# No apparent effect after editing some JSON in the memory of a Flash process

Tags: flash

I was trying to change the values of a Flash game which loads the SWF and some JSON over a HTTPS site. So changing the values of JSON was not possible using browser cache.

I changed the values of that JSON by editing the memory of the Adobe Flash process by loading it in [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/). Still I wasn't able to see the changed values inside Firefox.

Can anybody guide as to what protects the changed values from reflecting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hard to say with so little info, but I suspect that you edited the data after it has already been parsed by the game code. You probably need to intercept the moment it arrives from the remote server and change it then.

Comment: ...which can be easily done with [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/).